# Xcode 7.0 beta 4 not detect swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have installed Xcode 7.0 beta 4 but,I think Xcode will able to detect swift 2.0 function in my code

```
    let array = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let stringRepresentation = array.joinWithSeparator("-")
    print(stringRepresentation)
```

Xcode shows error " '[String]' does not have a member named 'joinWithSeparator'", as shown in below image

[image]

Also when I run   'xcrun swift'  in terminal it show

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.47.1 700.0.59.1). Type :help for assistance.
1>
```

and here I am getting stumped, not able to run swift 2.0 code.

Answer (score 2):

`joinWithSeparator` appeared in Xcode beta **6**.

Answer (score 2):

> **Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.0 beta 6** onwards uses `joinWithSeparator()` instead of join():

but you can get output using `join`

```
  let array = ["1", "2", "3"]
  let stringRepresentation = "-".join(array)
  print(stringRepresentation)  //output- 1-2-3
```

Comment: I am using 'alamofire' and it uses 'joinWithSeparator', and they say it's working on swift 2.0 and I am getting error

Comment: yes but you are using xcode 7.0 beta 4.0 and method `joinWithSeparator`  you can use  `xcode 7.0 beta 6.0` onwards...you can use `Join` instead and it will work for sure